# xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:9000' on Server

Tags: express, npm, server, gruntjs, mean-stack

I am using cloud digital server with IP  http://192.241.160.194 with Dokku & OS Ubuntu 16.04.

I have to deploy a mean stack project on this server. On my local machine I am using grunt server to run this project. On my local system i am using Ubuntu 16.04.

On server I have Installed npm, bower, nodejs, grunt server and mongodb successfully. But When I want to run grunt server. It gives me below error.

```
Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /root/Test/node_modules/open/vendor/xdg-open "http://localhost:9000"
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:9000'
```

I have tried both of these commands:

1. `grunt serve`
2. `grunt serve --force`

I have also installed browser on server. Also try to reinstall grunt-cli but found same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Server doesn't have graphics library. so we can not open browser on server. we need to run express server that will run grunt as well. For runing express server.
Put app in production and run command
node ./server